# Haskell learning environments

Tags: haskell, ide, editor, haskell-platform

after using plt-scheme for htdp and lispworks
personal edition for touretsky's intro to symbolic computation; i
would like to more about functional programming using haskell.
But i am spoiled using the above ide's. I started reading
learnyouahaskell  but when the discussion  goes to use your
favorite editor i blank out . I did download the haskell platform
and can use ghci in the terminal but 'linking' to an editor
seems to be a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are my IDE/Editor choices for Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504/what-are-my-ide-editor-choices-for-haskell)

Answer (score 2):

If developing environments qualify as learning environments:

- [leksah](http://www.leksah.org/index.html)
- [WinHugs (Windows)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/WinHugs)
- [EclipseFP](http://eclipsefp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tmux, then send from vim to ghci using the tslime plugin.

tmux: http://tmux.sourceforge.net/

tslime: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3023